# Buff the mighty - half-pint?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races

Are there any **small sized creatures with a bonus to their strength score?**

Ideally, I'd like one/some with as close an ECL to zero as possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Small Races with Strength Bonus

I’ve found three:

- Earth Mephling, *Planar Handbook*, +2 Str, Cha, −2 Dex, Int. Humanoid (Extraplanar). Gains a Burrow speed, a Breath Attack, a +1 Caster Level bonus on [Earth] spells. LA +1.
- Marrulurk, *Sandstorm*, +2 Str, +6 Dex, +4 Con, +6 Wis, +4 Cha. Yes, that is +22 in ability score bonuses, and yes, that is **insane**. They also get tons of other stuff, like 2d6 Sneak Attack and a Cha-based Death Attack, Point-blank Shot and Rapid Shot as bonus feats, +2 Natural Armor, lots of skill bonuses (Hide, Move Silently, Listen), Poison Use. 3 Monstrous Humanoid RHD and LA +1. Relatively high ECL but boy, is it worth it for the right build.
- Windrazor, *Monster Manual II*, +2 Str, +4 Dex, +2 Wis, −2 Int, −4 Cha. Main draw is the Fly 40’ (good), though they do have two Claws and a Bite, Improved Critical for both of those, and can scare people with crits. 2 Outsider RHD and LA +2. Not really worth it at ECL 4.

### Templates with Strength Bonus

Aside from those, you can take any Small race and apply a Template to it for bonuses to Str. Of course, Templates usually involve LA, which almost always isn’t worth it. Still, for completeness’s sake...

#### Actually Viable

Basically, LA +1 templates that are actually close to being *worth* an LA +1, and grant Strength.

- Draconic, *Races of the Dragon*, +2 Str, LA +1. Definitely the best way to make a random race “dragonish.” Well, other than taking levels in Dragonfire Adept, or taking a Dragonblood variant of the race, if one exists...
- Feral, *Savage Species*, +4 Str, LA +1. Quite possibly the best template out there... depending on how you read *Savage Species*’s ambiguous rules. If it scales with any HD (including Class Levels), rather than merely RHD, it’s amazing, quite possibly better than LA +1. If not... it’s OK-ish? Great if you’ve actually *got* RHD, I suppose, they pull some double-duty... The main draw (Pounce) requires 4 HD.
- Mineral Warrior, *Underdark*, +2 Str, LA +1. Actually quite good. Many consider it **too** good.
- Lolth-touched, *Monster Manual IV*, +6 Str, LA +1. If it weren’t for the fact that this involves **having Lolth touch you**, this would be excellent. Again, probably *better* than LA +1.

#### Other Templates...

That have a Strength bonus, can be legally applied to a Small PC, and leave that PC Small.

These are... pretty much garbage, as far as I can tell at a glance. LA +3 or greater is something I personally won’t even consider allowing in my games (barring *Unearthed Arcana*’s Gestalt variant, though even then...). To the best of my knowledge, none are really worth it, and even if some were, the sheer *skewing* that they’d do to your stats (ability scores too good, HD, HP, and Saves too weak) is just bad for a game. Still, they’re here.

- Half-earth Elemental, *Manual of the Planes* 3.5 update, +4 Str, LA +3.
- Half-water Elemental, *Manual of the Planes* 3.5 update, +2 Str, LA +3.
- Alu-demon, *Dragon* vol. 355, +2 Str, LA +4.
- Half-celestial, *Monster Manual*, +4 Str, LA +4.
- Half-fiend, *Monster Manual*, +4 Str, LA +4.
- Half-Janni, *Sandstorm*, +2 Str, LA +3.
- Lemorian, *Dungeon* vol. 143 or vol. 146, +4 Str, LA +4.
- Half-dragon, *Monster Manual*, +8 Str, LA +3. Most Str/LA, but really not worth it without being Large for the wings. (not really worth it *anyway*)
- Half-scrag, *Fiend Folio*, +6 Str, LA +4.
- Half-troll, *Fiend Folio*, +6 Str, LA +4.
- Gheden, *Dragon* vol. 313, +4 Str, LA +1. Looks good from this synopsis, but has Dex/Con/Int −2, Cha −4, and a bunch of Undead vulnerabilities without actually being Undead. Still, LA +1’s workable; it does get some of those Undead immunities.
- Ghul, *Dragon* vol. 313, +2 Str, LA +3.
- Half-vampire, *Libris Mortis*, +2 Str, LA +2.
- Katane, *Dragon* vol. 313, +2 Str, LA +4.
- Earth Elemental Creature, *Manual of the Planes* 3.5 update, +2 Str, LA +4.
- Magma Elemental Creature, *Manual of the Planes* 3.5 update, +2 Str, LA +5.
- Corrupted, *Dragon* vol. 350, +4 Str, LA +5.
- Stoneboned, *Dragon* vol. 350, +4 Str, LA +2. Gains Powerful Build but you can stay Small.
- Mummified, *Libris Mortis*, +8 Str, LA +4.
- Animus, *Dragon* vol. 339, +4 Str, LA +4.
- Gravetouched Ghoul, *Libris Mortis*, +2 Str, LA +2.
- Vampire, *Monster Manual* or [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vampire.htm), +6 Str, LA +8.
- Savage Vampire, *Dragon* vol. 348, +6 Str, LA +6.
- Shadow Vampire, *Dragon* vol. 348, +4 Str, LA +10.
- Dry Lich, *Sandstorm*, +2 Str, LA +5 (waived if gained through Walker in the Waste prestige class)
- Drowned One, *Dragon* vol. 106, +6 Str, LA +3.
- Fleshvigor, *Dragon* vol. 315, +2 Str, LA +1 (must already be Undead).
- Voidmind, *Monster Manual III*, +4 Str, LA +1 (but really unplayable, since a Mind Flayer can *dominate* you at any distance, no save).
- Dustform, *Sandstorm*, +4 Str, LA +2. Loses all base creature’s special qualities.
- Hooded Pupil, *Libris Mortis*, +2 Str, LA +4.
- Spellwarped, *Monster Manual III*, +4 Str, LA +3.

Many thanks to [Chet Erez](http://chet.kindredcircle.org/), whose amazing indices make such thorough answers possible. Note that I have not personally checked most of the Templates in the last part of the answer; Chet’s indices have had some minor errors in the past, so check the books before use.

Comment: +1 is the first extraplanar/outsider? I dig the marrulurk, too.

Comment: @LitheOhm: Mephlings are Humanoid (Extraplanar). Unfortunately, Earth is in many ways the weakest of the lot: the other three get a positive ability score (+2 something alongside the +2 Cha/&minus;2 Int), and Air Mephlings get the ability to Fly (albeit with a speed of 10&rsquo;). Earth Mephlings do get a Burrow speed, though, which is pretty awesome.

Comment: Well played sir, well played indeed. Found what I was looking for here, and more :)

Comment: mummified, lolth-touched marrulurk...